# WS on HTTP vs WSS on HTTPS

Tags: security, http, https, websocket

I've read that WS only works on HTTP, and that WSS works on both HTTP and HTTPS. Are WSS (Secure Web Socket) connections just as secure on an HTTP server as they are on an HTTPS server? Is a Web Socket Secure (WSS) connection still encrypted through TLS/SSL if the website/server is not?

Comment: "*I know wss works on both http and https*" Huh?

Comment: Maybe I should have said "I have read that" instead of "I know"?

Comment: What David meant is that the information you've read, _"wss works on both http and https"_, is wrong. See my answer.

Comment: So, if the connection is http the WebSocket must be "ws" and if the connection is https the WebSocket must be "wss"?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

> Is a web socket secure (wss) connection still encrypted through TLS/SSL if the website/server is not?

Yes.

> Are wss (Secure Web Socket) connections just as secure on an http server as they are on an https server?

Yes (see above). There is one thing to note: if the HTML/JavaScript that opens the secure WebSocket connection comes over non-secure HTTP, the WebSocket connection is still secure, but an attacker might modify the HTML/JavaScript while being sent from the Web server to browser. A HTTP connection isn't protected against man-in-the-middle sniffing or modification.

Comment: Ah plain TCP connection (non-TLS) is suspect to t and man-in-the-middle attacks.

Comment: Do you have a reference for your first answer?

Comment: RFC6455 specifies that wss runs secure. The hosting env (browser or else) does not matter. You can also look at wire dumps to confirm browser beh.

Comment: A non-TLS connection is subject to a variety of attacks that a TLS connection is not.  So, NO a non-TLS connection is NOT just as secure as  TLS connection.

Comment: This answer contain misleading information. [Takahiko Kawasaki's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34554243/5373629) should be marked as the correct one. Specifically, `wss` operates ONLY over HTTPS, as read on the [RFC 6455, Section 11.1.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455#section-11.1.2): `A |wss| URI [...]
   indicates that traffic over that connection is to be protected via
   TLS.`

Comment: I kinda agree with @AlvaroGutierrezPerez but to be fair you CAN open a wss in your html through just HTTP. Though like stated and to elaborate upon: an attacker can still modify your HTML to only open a ws connection (to be able to monitor/attack the websocket as well) over HTTP.

Comment: Seems like there is a lot of confusion here;) Point is, with browsers, there are 2 connections involved: a) the one to fetch the HTML and JS files via HTTP or HTTPS and b) the actual WebSocket connection, which only _starts_ as a HTTP or HTTPS connection. Now you can have a) done via HTTP, while b) is done via HTTPS upgraded to WSS. But you can NOT have a) via HTTPS, and then b) via HTTP not being upgraded to WSS, but using plain WS. This is explicitly forbidden for _browser_ WebSocket clients (and browsers enforce it). Non-browser WebSocket clients don't even have a)

Comment: The answer seems to me a bit confusing. `wss` over `http`  (not `https`) is very unusual idea. I think the answer can be improved if this moment clarified a bit more.

Comment: @shitpoet I am considering http + wss right now. My case is that we ship routers, that must have a domain name in LAN, for example be accessible via http://open.wrt - we can't have https here, because we can issue only self-signed SSL cert for local domain name which will cause warning in all browsers if used. But on page loaded the real data must be transferred over another wss connection for security purposes. The only issue I face now is that wss connection fails. Maybe I have not set it up correctly...

Answer (score 133):

*"wss works on both http and https"* ??? This is a strange phrase.

`wss` is secure only because it means "WebSocket protocol over **https**". WebSocket protocol itself is not secure. There is no Secure WebSocket protocol, but there are just "WebSocket protocol over http" and "WebSocket protocol over https". See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34554045/1174054).

As the author of **[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** (WebSocket client library for Java), I also doubt the phrase *"if the HTML/JavaScript that opens the secure WebSocket connection comes over non-secure HTTP, the WebSocket connection is still secure"* in the answer by oberstet.

**Read [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) (The WebSocket Protocol) to reach the right answer.** To become a true engineer, don't avoid reading RFCs. Only searching technical blogs and StackOverflow for answers will never bring you to the right place.

Comment: A HTML page loaded by a browser over HTTP (not HTTPS) which contains JavaScript can open both a non.secure (ws) as well as secure (wss). A HTML page that loads over HTTPS can only open a wss connection (not a ws connection). You don't have to believe me: just try it.

Comment: What you stated will only work if the web server also listens on https.

Comment: Most of the answers are confusing, and make it sound as if wss was possible from http connection, like there was wss-specific tls establishment over plain tcp/ws connection.

Comment: WebSocket doesn't go over HTTPS, it goes over TLS. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-4.2.2, where [RFC5246] refers to TLS. ws->wss is similar to http->https, **SSL/TLS/security** adds the S. Only the initial request before the upgrade is HTTPS.

Comment: 'I also doubt the phrase' less reading and more doing! Oberstet is right and you are not! Misinforming people is not nice!