# WSS works on http?

Tags: http, ssl, web, websocket

It is possible having a wss protocol over http ? i've read on a forum that ws work with http, but wss works only with https ?
Is that true ?

Cause i'm trying to test it on my wamp on localhost, but not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websockets - wss on http vs. wss on https](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791107/websockets-wss-on-http-vs-wss-on-https)

Comment: sligthly different, and also no response satisfaying me has been made

Answer (score 27):

`ws` tells a WebSocket client library to use `http` to connect to a WebSocket server. Likewise, `wss` tells a WebSocket client library to use `https` to connect to a WebSocket server. Just that. "ws protocol" and "wss protocol" are strange words. "WebSocket protocol" is the right word. WebSocket protocol can be used over both plain HTTP connections (`http`) and secure HTTP connections (`https`).

Note that communication between a WebSocket client and a WebSocket server starts as a normal HTTP protocol. To start WebSocket communication, a WebSocket client sends a request like below to a WebSocket server (This is an excerpt from RFC 6455, [1.2. Protocol Overview](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-1.2)).

```
GET /chat HTTP/1.1
Host: server.example.com
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==
Origin: http://example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat, superchat
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
```

As you can see, this is a normal HTTP `GET` request. A WebSocket server can wait for this kind of requests on an unsecured port (`http`, 80 is the default) or on a secured port (`https`, 443 is the default). It's up to WebSocket servers.

If a WebSocket server you are using is waiting for requests on an unsecured port, pass `ws` to a WebSocket client library you are using. Otherwise, if the WebSocket server is waiting for requests on a secured port, pass `wss` to the WebSocket client library.

Some implementations of WebSocket client libraries accept not only `ws` and `wss` but also `http` and `https` just for developers' convenience.

"WSS on http" is a strange word. On the other hand, "WebSocket protocol on http" and "WebSocket protocol on https" make sense.

Comment: I think the question was about: can I connect through wss if page was opened with http?