# WebSocketException: Unsupported URL scheme 'https'

Tags: flutter, dart, websocket, stomp

I have created a simple chat application using `Flutter`, `Spring Boot` and `RabbitMq` as technologies.
when i try to connect the stompClient it occurs error. Here I'm using `https://` request for connecting. Previously, it worked properly, after migrating Fluter it was not working. (Previous flutter version is 2.2.3 and upgraded to 3.10.0)

**Code I implemented is as follows**

```
 _stompClient = StompClient(
          config: StompConfig(
            url: 'https://app/chat/web-socket',
            stompConnectHeaders: headers,
            onConnect: (frame) {

              Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 10), (_) {
                _stompClient.send(
                    destination: messageSendUri,
                    headers: headers,
                    body: jsonEncode(body));
              });
            },
            beforeConnect: () async {
              print('Trying to connect...');
              await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1));
              print('Connecting...');
            },
            onStompError: (frame) => print(frame.body),
            onWebSocketError: (error) => print(error.toString()),
          ),
        );

      }
```

**when it run, it occurs following errors**

```
I/flutter (25662): Trying to connect...
I/flutter (25662): WebSocketException: Unsupported URL scheme 'https'
I/flutter (25662): WebSocketException: Unsupported URL scheme 'https'
I/flutter (25662): WebSocketException: Unsupported URL scheme 'https'
I/flutter (25662): Connecting...
I/flutter (25662): WebSocketException: Unsupported URL scheme 'https'
...
```

Is https requests not allowed? How can I fix this issue?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

_stompClient = StompClient(
config: StompConfig.SockJs(
url: 'https://app/chat/web-socket',
stompConnectHeaders: headers,

**Add SockJs After StompConfig. You don't need to change the url**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to WebSocket but using http address to it.

```
https://app/chat/web-socket
```

WebSocket endpoint should with `wss` not '`http` or 'https`. Somehting like

```
wss://app/chat/web-socket
```

More Info [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34532006/wss-works-on-http)