# Website login system - authentication with websocket server

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, websocket

I need a login system for my website through which i can securely authenticate my users on my ws server. **The client side code is a javascript function, which is able to send a token over as a packet and the server side code gets the packet and gets the string out of it.** From here i could connect with a datebase or whatever.

My problem is, i don't want to send over the username and password, because this seems very **unsecure** to me. Is there any way to authenticate through a secure way? I just want to let the server check if the user is loggin in and if that's the case which account it is. I was thinking about **google auth**, but i don't know where to start.

I hope you can help me.
Kind regrads,

*Simon*

Comment: You can implement authorization outside websocket, and set cookie with Bearer token, and start sending that token in your websocket

Comment: I found this online: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow Do you think i could work with this too? Like as you said sending the token as a cookie, but instead of the bearer token the access token?

Comment: Yes, OAuth works similar, but anyway you need implement google auth outside of websocket connection, and after login, you can use your access token

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can use WSS instead of WS. WSS is secure web socket. It can be implemented over HTTP or HTTPS. See this related post: [html5 Websocket with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745249/html5-websocket-with-ssl)

Comment: My problem here is, that it's some kind of game server and i am sending hundreds of packets a second. This makes it more difficult to change from http to https.

Comment: Well you can still have WSS over http. See this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791107/websockets-wss-on-http-vs-wss-on-https