# If I have already a HTTPS can I use wss, or I need to pay additional fee?

Tags: security, https, websocket, wss

I'm wondering if I have to pay additional fee, if I already bought a HTTPS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Websockets - wss on http vs. wss on https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791107/websockets-wss-on-http-vs-wss-on-https)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you do not. WSS can be used with or without HTTPS and is inherantly secure and encrypted regardless of your protocol/encryption.

Comment: Uhhh, if you don't use an https server, then lots of security protections are lost such as man-in-the-middle protection, domain hijaacking, certificate revocation, etc...  So, it is NOT the same when using an http server by any definition of security.  You can, however, use wss with your existing https server just fine.