# Secure websockets for ASP.NET Core

Tags: ssl, asp.net-core, websocket, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

Is there any WebSockets solution/middleware for ASP.NET Core which includes out of the box ability for configuring connections over ssl, I just can't find such a thing in [standard implementation](https://github.com/aspnet/WebSockets).

Comment: Websockets and ssl operate at very different layers, there's no overlapping config. Configure your server for https and use the normal websockets middleware.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html5 Websocket with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9745249/html5-websocket-with-ssl)

Comment: With ASP.NET Core configured for HTTPS, just use `wss://` for your WebSocket connection.

Comment: Websockets follow the lead of the main connection, i.e. if your site is served over HTTPS, the browser will also use the `wss` protocol for websockets.

Comment: Read answers to understand how it works:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791107/wss-on-http-vs-wss-on-https