# insecure WebSocket connection on reactjs deployed application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-deployment, cloud-foundry

I have some problems with the deployment of my *React.js* application on the web.

I tried with *azure* and with *pivotal* *DevOps* environment. Both don't work.

I don't call any websocket. The only externals connections are with firebase (npm package) and maybe with some others npm package. All others static links (js and css files) are with *https* protocol.

My website is currently deployed below:

https://smad-app.cfapps.io/
[image: Image of the website]

If I deploy in local with "serve -s build". I have any errors.

Do you have any tips or steps to fix/debug my deployment ?

Comment: You are connecting to insecure WS instead of WSS.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26791107/wss-on-http-vs-wss-on-https

Comment: @ritaj Yes but as explained I don't create any web sockets in my app. How to find wich npm package cause me troubles ?

Comment: @alexdess you said yourself that you use firebase

Comment: Yes but I can't choose how firebase create its websockets ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem, I did the following steps according to [this post](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8084) to fix my problem:

1. Open my_project_root\node_modules\react-dev-utils\webpackHotDevClient.js
2. Change the connection object with the following lines:

   ```
   // Connect to WebpackDevServer via a socket.
   var connection = new WebSocket(
       url.format({
           protocol: window.location.protocol === 'https:' ? 'wss' : 'ws',
           hostname: window.location.hostname,
           port: window.location.port,
           // Hardcoded in WebpackDevServer
           pathname: '/sockjs-node',
           slashes: true,
           })
   );
   ```

Comment: Hi there, I put the changes to the file but I still get the same error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Hi, Where is compiled you application ? Is it working locally ?